# How do I select the highlighted value from the DOM?

Tags: jquery

[image]

I tried to select the element by an attribute value, as such:

```
var item = jQuery("[name='directorSequence']");
```

But I don't know how to actually get the value of the attribute `"aria-valuenow="` ... which in this case is 4.

Can anyone give me a hand?

EDIT -

This is the rest of the code:

```
detailRow.find(".directorsOrRecipients").kendoGrid({
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://z/x/api/Awards/directors/" + awardTitleId,
                type: "GET"
            },
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "AwardDirectorId",
                fields: {
                    "AwardDirectorId": { editable: false, type: "number", nullable: true },
                    "namefirstlast": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    "directorsequence": { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { min: 1 } },
                    "isonballot": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    "concatenation": { editable: true, type: "string" },
                    "MoreNames": { editable: true, type: "number", validation: { min: 0 } },
                }
            }
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "AwardDirectorId", title: "Award Director Id", hidden: true },
        { field: "namefirstlast", title: "Name", editor: namesAutoComplete },
        { field: "directorsequence", title: "Director Sequence", format: "{0:n0}" },
        { field: "isonballot", title: "On ballot?", editor: onBallotDropDownEditor },
        { field: "concatenation", title: "Concatenation" },
        { field: "MoreNames", title: "More names?", format: "{0:n0}" },
        { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: 100 }],
    sortable: true,
    sort: { field: "namefirstlast", dir: "desc" },
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add New Director/Recipient" }],
    save: function(e)
    {
        debugger;

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            debugger;
            var item = jQuery("[name='directorSequence']");
            var x = item.attr("aria-valuenow");
        });



        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/Take3/api/awards/directors",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $.parseJSON(directorData)
        }).done(function()
        {
            detailRow.find(".directorsOrRecipients").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
        });
    },
    edit: function()
    {
    }
});
```

Comment: style is display:none, pick another picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var item = jQuery("[name='directorSequence']");
item.attr("aria-valuenow");
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/KmnAA/

Comment: is item.attr("aria-valuenow"); supposed to return a value? I'm getting undefined for this.

Comment: @Rj. You have to make sure this code is inside the $(document).ready() function.

Comment: Hanlet, that still does not work. Please take a look at my updated OP. Look above the AJAX function.

Comment: Well, I did not know the code was any more complex. You need to add the code I gave you after that element is in available in the DOM, something I cannot know from the code you've shared. When is that input added into the page? After the ajax call? On page load? When?

Comment: the value is input before the ajax call. the ajax call gets executed on the save event button click.

Comment: Yes, but is it available on page load?

Comment: the elemnent is there on page load but the value 4 is entered by the user later.

Comment: Then that's when you want to check it, when you know it's going to change. Be it on element.blur() or something of the sort.

Comment: There's actually an easier way to do this with Kendo. I just figured it out. but I'll accept your answer here regardless. I had to do: save: function(e)
        {
            var x = e.model.directorsequence;
}; Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

use the `attr()` method.

```
$('input[name=directorSequence]').attr('aria-valuenow')
```

[jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: NO! Awesome display picture.

Comment: im getting undefined for this as well.